# Проблема с шаблоном сайта конкретно с меню

Tags: html, javascript, css

скачал шаблон, красивый и без сильных выкрутасов. Так вот столкнулся с проблемой с вертикальным меню.
Хотел на стр сделать меню справа. Но не получается т. к почему то контент прописан только слева и до половины стр а больше его растянуть вправо не получается, т. е на 100% как он должен текст не размещается! скрины могу привести:
http://firepic.org/images/2014-01/08/g7kyrknge8y3.png
http://firepic.org/images/2014-01/08/ouv0xb9bgjf4.png
http://firepic.org/images/2014-01/08/828xpx5m9s4j.png

Проблема еще в том я не могу найти в css этот параметр. вернее есть но совсем не то. не отвечает за текст.
В java покапался тоже не нашел
Может кто нить помочь? а то я уже устал все перебирать. для наглядности выложил сайт на поддомен.

http://2.art-massage-spa.ru/index-2.html

Answer (score 1):

class  `art-layout-cell { width: 100% }` нужно сделать, в данный момент стоит 50%